# How to concat an integer value with a string in DB2 procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, concatenation

I have a variable, `price dec(5,0)`. How can I concat a static string "dollar" to that and save as a `char(10)`?

If the price is 55555, the result should be 55555 Dollar and this should be saved as a `char(11)`.

How can I do it? I tried casting and just concat using '+', but it was not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concat operator in DB2 is a double pipe, `||`.

Also, you'll need to `cast` the decimal value to a char before you can concatenate.

Something like:

```
select cast(55555 as char(5)) || ' Dollar' from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 3):

No casting is needed - both of the exampples below work:

CONCAT(55555, ' Dollar') as "Test Column"

OR

55555 || ' Dollar' AS "Test Column 2"